# github delete commit history for already deleted github repo

Tags: github

I have deleted a github repo but commit history still remains. Can someone help me with some command so that I can delete complete commit history from github account.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be helpful for you. https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-remove-my-commits-from-the-contributions-graph-on-GitHub